# MYSQL Backward compatible to 5.1.1?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, backwards-compatibility

I have a Wordpress site that was developed on a server running the latest version of MYSQL, however, I've just found out the host server (BT) is running 5.1.1. and they have no plans to upgrade anytime soon.

Does anyone know if there is a way of converting the database so it runs on 5.1.1 with no issues caused re the site being built in the latest version of Wordpress?

If this is a massive issue, then I do have some alternative hosting options, but I'm hoping for a way forward re conversion - any geniuses out there?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that BT is running MySQL 5.1.1. That version was never released. It was an internal development milestone in 2005.

The first GA release of the 5.1 branch was 5.1.30 in 2008. The last 5.1 release was 5.1.73 in 2013. But after 2013, 5.1 has been in "sustaining support" which means they will not make any new versions or fixes.

You shouldn't deploy to a hosting site that still runs any 5.1.x version. A site that is so far behind is probably behind on other software too, and I would not be surprised if they have known security vulnerabilities.

Wordpress officially requires MySQL 5.6 or later, according to https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/.

You could try to test that by testing on MySQL 5.1 (assuming you can find an installation package of MySQL 5.1). Use `mysqldump` to export data from your 5.6 database server and then import that to MySQL 5.1. The output of `mysqldump` wraps newer syntax in special comments that will be ignored by older versions of MySQL Server.

Regardless, my recommendation is:

1. Find another hosting service running MySQL 5.6 or 5.7.
2. Develop and test your site with the same versions of all software (MySQL, PHP, Apache, etc.) that you will eventually deploy to.

Comment: Thanks for the info Bill. This gives me even less confidence in their support, as they themselves told me the BT connect server was running 5.1.1. which is clearly not true (believe me, I have more confidence in your information than I do in theirs). I do have another host lined up so will be recommending as you say.